# Function to check data in environment - R

Tags: r

I know this in a environment issue but I need help to figure out where I am going wrong.

I have the need to check data exists in the a knit environment (Rmd). I'd like to write a function that can be used inside other functions:

```
## Function to check x exists in some environment
data_check_fun <- function(x, e = parent.frame()) {

  ## Use substitute so I can pass in unquoted variable
  df_name <- deparse(substitute(x))

  ## Check env looking in
  print("looking in env: ")
  print(e)

  exists(df_name, envir = e)
}

## Create df in Global env
df <- data.frame()

## Try function (works)
> data_check_fun(x = df)
[1] "looking in env: "
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
[1] TRUE
> data_check_fun(x = not_df)
[1] "looking in env: "
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
[1] FALSE

## Create new env: knit_env
knit_env <- new.env()

## Put df in knit_env
knit_env$knit_df <- data.frame()

## Check df is in knit_env
> ls(knit_env)
[1] "knit_df"

## Try function (works)
> data_check_fun(x = knit_df, e = knit_env)
[1] "looking in env: "
<environment: 0xda4ac60>
[1] TRUE
> data_check_fun(x = not_df, e = knit_env)
[1] "looking in env: "
<environment: 0xda4ac60>
[1] FALSE

## Create new function e.g. to plot, which calls data_check fun
plot_function <- function(plot_data, env) {
  data_check_fun(x = plot_data, e = env)
}

## Pass data from knit_env into plot function (does not work)
> plot_function(plot_data = knit_df, env = knit_env)
[1] "looking in env: "
<environment: 0xda4ac60>
[1] FALSE
```

I think it is because `data_check_fun` inside `plot_function` is looking for something now called `plot_data` which doesn't exist. Is there a way I could do this. Ideally I don't want to quote the argument being passed into `plot_function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if the first argument of `data_check_fun` were simply defined to be a character string.  Using non-standard evaluation, as in the question, tends to require significant additional effort but if you really want to do it without explicitly quoting the arguments then capture the call, build up the new call and evaluate it yourself like this:

```
plot_function2 <- function(plot_data, env) {
  mf <- match.call()
  m <- match(c("plot_data", "env"), names(mf), 0L)
  mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
  names(mf)[m] <- c("x", "e")[m > 0]
  mf[[1L]] <- quote(data_check_fun)
  eval.parent(mf)
}

# test
plot_function2(plot_data = knit_df, env = knit_env)
```

See the source code for `lm` for another examqple.

Comment: Oof ok so yes it would be a lot easier for me to just quote the argument. Glad I checked. Thanks for the providing a way to do it if I want to in future.